# Check value existance while performing a UPDATE query

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mysql-error-1093

I need to perform a simple update query where the update should only be done, if there is no value with updating value (item_name). For example,

DB table [item_types]

```
item_id(PK) | item_name
```

Assuming there exist item_id with 6, My attempt is

```
UPDATE item_types as k SET k.item_name = 'item_1' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM item_types as a WHERE a.item_name = 'item_1') AND k.item_id = '6'
```

But this gives me error

```
"You can't specify target table 'k' for update in FROM clause"
```

Could you please explain the error here and how can I achieve this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put a unique restraint on the item_name field and catch the error.

Comment: yes, it is good way of getting this done, but I need to figure out what the problem with my query, Could you please explain ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can use an alias for a table in an insert statement. Also use , rather than AND.

Try

```
UPDATE item_types SET item_name = 'item_1' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM 
item_types as a WHERE a.item_name = 'item_1') , item_id = '6'
```

Comment: your statement giving me a syntax error with mySQL, are you sure about syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

As Toby suggested, you can't use an alias in the UPDATE line. Try the following syntax though:

```
UPDATE item_types 
SET item_name = 'item_1' 
FROM item_types k
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM item_types as a WHERE a.item_name = 'item_1') 
AND k.item_id = '6'
```

hth, R